# Using custom class methods in web service client (C#)

Tags: c#, class, service, web, client

I've been doing quite a bit a learning over the past couple of days and I believe I've come to a conclusion.  I would like to ask if my current understanding is correct, as I've had a very difficult time getting a "straight" answer to my specific problem based on Google searches.

I have a C# class library (.dll) with some classes that are used across multiple projects, including customClass (namespace myDLL).

I have a C# web service.  One of the web service functions has an "out customClass [] myCustomClass" array argument.

I have a C# web service client.  I want to be able to use customClass in the client.  Here is a list of questions:

1)  Is it true that the customClass array that is returned to the web service client is NOT the same type as an array of type myDLL.customClass (even though it is intuitive to assume that it would be)?

2)  Is there any easy way to cast/convert the customClass array in the web service client to the type myDLL.customClass?  I'd prefer to not have to write supporting code or manually edit reference.cs.  It is my belief that there is NOT such an easy method of conversion, although it can be done with supporting conversion code.

3)  It is my belief that the output of web services is meant to be *only* data (in general).  To expect that a client will get class behavior along with data "easily/natively" when using the web service WSDL is not an expectation supported by the web service/web service client model.  Is this belief generally correct?

I appreciate any help.  If anyone has an nice, straightforward links about this topic, I wouldn't be surprised I've already read it, but I will definitely be all eyes :).

Thanks,
Richard